# Trouble Extracting Data with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm practicing extracting data from an XML site and I'm using Nokogiri to read and parse. I need to analyze the data but for now, I'm just trying to get an output with no success.

I have the following code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/macbeth.xml"))

doc.xpath('//PERSONA').each do |char_element|
  puts char_element.text
end
```

I'm simply trying to read the characters off the XML website, but I'm not getting any results when I run it in the terminal. I also tried just writing a simple xpath call such as the one below:

```
doc.xpath("//PERSONA")
```

or

```
doc.xpath("PLAY TITLE")
```

And I get either an error or it simply acts as if nothing was entered.
I have put a simple function to test it so I know it's reading it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read XML file as a HTML one.
Please try that example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/macbeth.xml"))

doc.xpath('//PERSONA').each{|ce| p ce.text }
"DUNCAN, king of Scotland."
"MALCOLM"
"DONALBAIN"
"MACBETH"
"BANQUO"
"MACDUFF"
"LENNOX"
"ROSS"
"MENTEITH"
"ANGUS"
"CAITHNESS"
"FLEANCE, son to Banquo."
"SIWARD, Earl of Northumberland, general of the English forces."
"YOUNG SIWARD, his son."
"SEYTON, an officer attending on Macbeth."
"Boy, son to Macduff. "
"An English Doctor. "
"A Scotch Doctor. "
"A Soldier."
"A Porter."
"An Old Man."
"LADY MACBETH"
"LADY MACDUFF"
"Gentlewoman attending on Lady Macbeth. "
"HECATE"
"Three Witches."
"Apparitions."
"Lords, Gentlemen, Officers, Soldiers, Murderers, Attendants, and Messengers. "
```

Please be sure you're using `Nokogiri::XML` instead of `Nokogiri::HTML`

Comment: @fancy_daniel, please consider to mark my answer as correct if it really was so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @retgoat, I thought I had tried that but I guess I did it wrong. Thanks for your help.